# "The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context" while using Interface class IUpdate

Tags: c#

Hello everyone im trying to make a program which accepts updates from an text file as approved updates into WSUS. So in my txt file are some updates which I want to approve to specific groups in my wsus-server. Here is how I try to do this:

```
string test = comboBox1.Text;
IUpdateServer server = AdminProxy.GetUpdateServer("wsus", false, 8530);
UpdateCollection update = server.GetUpdates();

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(file))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < update.Count; i++)
    {
        if (line == update[i].Title)
        {
            SiemensApprovedUpdates.Add(update[i]);
        }
    }
}
foreach (IUpdate SiemensApprovedUpdate in SiemensApprovedUpdates)
{
    SiemensApprovedUpdate.Approve(UpdateApprovalAction.Install, server.GetComputerTargetGroups()[1]); // error is here
}
```

Now I get the error: `"The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context"` after a while that I ran my code. I think im reffering to the ComputerTargetGroup in a wrong way, but I have no idea on what to change the last line in the code to.

Any tips are appriciated a lot, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not an error, it is a warning from the debugger.  It sees a COM function call take longer than a minute.  That isn't healthy, and a sign of deadlock in the thread's dispatcher, but it doesn't look like fast code either.  Just press F5 to keep going to ensure that the call eventually completes.  You can then turn the warning off.  Ensuring that your UI is not frozen while this call hangs it is another task.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for this answer, im oing to test this. I tested it and it worked. Tho it approved updates for every group and not just the group I assigned `[1]`

Comment: @HansPassant Do you think I can solve this with multithreading?

Comment: If you don't want your UI to go catatonic, who does, then yes.